# Automation through Jenkins fails on closing remote machine

Tags: selenium, jenkins, robotframework

I'm executing automation test cases through Jenkins on a remote machine. Test cases run fine as long as I don't close remote machine and once I close the remote machine automation fails in Jenkins.

Can you please let me know why does this happens. Even though slave is running on the remote machine.

Comment: what do you mean you close machine ?

Comment: I mean I disconnect from remote machine. It executes 2-3 test cases and then fails the build.

Comment: So, you're saying the test fails because you disconnect the machine that is being tested? How can the test possibly continue if the machine is disconnected?

Comment: Is the "remote machine" connected to Jenkins server as an agent?

Comment: Yes I have a slave agent running on that machine @pcjr

Comment: @BryanOakley No it's not the machine, it is the application that is being tested through that script.

Comment: @vyomverma What type of operating system is the remote machine? If its Windows, are you closing your remote desktop connection or are you logging out of the machine (so that no one is logged into the desktop)?

Comment: @pcjr It's a windows machine. I'm just disconnecting the connection as UI automation can run in the background.

Comment: @vyomverma Are you disconnecting the Jenkins server connection to the build agent (your windows machine)?

Comment: @pcjr no slave agent is always showing connected to remote machine.

Answer (score 0):

I've found that some types of tests require someone to be logged into the windows console (such as when using a Remote Desktop Client). This is because they need to do things like open browser windows, etc. This won't work if there isn't a user logged into the console. I think this is because Windows won't let a process open a window if no one is logged into the console. We RDC to these nodes as the build user (the same user the job runs as) and then close the RDC window (without logging out).